# Primary zone will not transfer to secondary zone

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Using DNS on Windows Server 2008, there is a constant struggle with adding primary and secondary zones. I will add a primary zone to NS1 for a new domain, edit it as needed, and when it's ready add the secondary zone to NS2. However, MOST of the time, the secondary zone remains in an error state, and will never acquire the primary zone data. I have gone back to domains a few weeks after adding them to find out that Windows never propagated the change.

Annoying.

Anyway, I recently updated SP1 to SP2 thinking this would help, but it hasn't. I added two new domains today, and spent an hour after the secondary zone would just not sync. During that time, the only error in the logs I had seen was for one of them where DNS complained about not being authoritative.

In order to eventually resolve the issue, I ended up deleting the primary zone, creating a new primary zone, and hitting "Apply" after each and every field change. For example, after modifying the serial number from "1" to a date appropriate "2010093001", I hit apply, and then the Primary Server (apply), Responsible Person (apply), and finally Name Servers (apply). After I did this, the secondary zone didn't waste any time getting the data.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the primary multi-homed, and are you restricting replication to name servers listed for the domain? I've seen windows make the transfer request off the wrong nic before and if it doesn't reverse resolve correctly then the xfer is denied.

Comment: Answering this a bit late, but I believe you hit the nail on the head. It seems that NS2 and NS3 zones either suffered from legacy "Only allow to these [old] IPs" settings or that NS3 was multi-homed and updating over a LAN IP and didn't match up to what NS1 was expecting. Thanks!